# R - improving e1071 tuning performance

Tags: r, svm

I am using the grid search method via svm.tune to get the optimal gamma and C parameter for my svm. The data set has 7M rows and 11 feature variables.

It seems that tuning on 5M rows of my data is taking a long time, or will run out of memory(when I reduce the range of grid search).

Does anyone have any advice on how I can improve performance? Scaling the features? Or perhaps reducing the number of rows for training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a grid search on a random subset of the data, then use the best parameters to train your svm on the whole dataset. Fitting a svm is both processor and memory hungry.

Comment: It is a fact that the training time of a svm does not scale linearly on the size of the data, take a look at this article for a possible solution to this problem:
http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/machine-learning-in-parallel-with-support-vector-machines

Comment: Would you mind adding the tuning function or parameters you used?